# Loop doesn't change content within div

Tags: javascript

This loop is supposed to increment the variable x every 15 seconds and depending upon what value x is the appropriate content is shown, the problem is that x doesn't increment.

```
        var x = 1;

        function slider() { 

            if (x > 4) {
            x = 1;
            }

            if (x == 1) {
                document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example one</h3></div>");
            } else if(x == 2) {
                document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example two</h3></div>");
            } else if (x == 3) {
                document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example three</h3></div>");
            } else {
                document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example four</h3></div>");
            }

        x++

        }

        setInterval(slider(), 15000);
```

Comment: You did not have any code to increment i. You need to have a x= x+ 1 or x++ somewhere.

Comment: Please don't downvote without adding your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing the variable x.

Change your code to:

```
var x = 1;

function slider() { 
    x++; // x incremented.
    if (x > 4) {
    x = 1;
    }

    if (x == 1) {
        document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example one</h3></div>");
    } else if(x == 2) {
        document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example two</h3></div>");
    } else if (x == 3) {
        document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example three</h3></div>");
    } else {
        document.writeln("<div id='picture_slider_info'><h3>Example four</h3></div>");
    }

}

setInterval(slider(), 15000);
```

Comment: yeah sorry i did have it i just deleted accidentally before

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `slider()`, instead, pass the function as argument to `setInterval`:

`setInterval(slider, 1500)`.

You are currently passing the return result of `slider()` which is `undefined` to `setInterval`.

Comment: that doesn't work at all it doesn't write it to the page at all

Comment: It is working, I just tested it. The problem is elsewhere. Did you try reducing the interval? 15 seconds are a lot of time to wait. Set it to 1.5seconds and see that it is actually working.

Comment: It works in Chrome. It can't possibly in any other browser since writing to the document clears ***all*** the html on the page, including your own script.

Comment: oh thats probably why then as i'm using opera

Answer (score 0):

Nikola Dimitroff is right.
I'm giving this as an answer to give you the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 1;
function slider() { 
  console.log(x);
  if (x > 4) { x = 1; }
  if (x == 1) { console.log("One"); }
  else if(x == 2) { console.log("Two"); }
  else if (x == 3) { console.log("Three"); }
  else { console.log("More"); }
  x++
  }
setInterval(slider, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```